# Spring DataSource configuration using JNDI

Tags: spring, jndi, bitronix

I am having trouble configuring the dataSource bean using JNDI in the Spring applicationContext.xml file.

This is how my applicationContext.xml entry looks like:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myApp" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

I have made an entry in web.xml:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/myApp</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
<resource-env-ref>
```

Context.xml file in Tomcat:

```
<Resource 
    auth="Container" 
    factory="bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceObjectFactory" 
    name="jdbc/myApp" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    uniqueName="jdbc/myApp" />
```

With these configuration I keep getting this error on Tomcat console:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/myApp] is not bound in this    Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
>       at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)

Please help me resolve this issue. It appears to me that the bitronix transaction factory in Context.xml is causing the issue.

Comment: What happens if you use 
`<beans:bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myApp"/>
    </beans:bean>` 
instead of `jee:jndi-lookup` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different jndi name, because in Tomcat all configured entries and resources are placed in the `java:comp/env` portion of the JNDI namespace and you need to specify that, as well:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/myApp" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```